# archive failed using xcode15

Tags: archive, xcode15

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKAJa.jpg)

archive failed using xcode15, but run successfully on debugging iphone,

xcode14.2 does not have this problem

=====================================================

PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/sword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mage-ios-dsifsnvwvxethjewoknlrdvajlxe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RENPHO/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MageFitness.build/Release-iphoneos/AI\ Gym.build/Script-23112B16D73A4B02959D4FE9.sh (in target 'AI Gym' from project 'MageFitness')
cd /Users/sword/Desktop/aigym/MageFitness
/bin/sh -c /Users/sword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mage-ios-dsifsnvwvxethjewoknlrdvajlxe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RENPHO/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MageFitness.build/Release-iphoneos/AI\\ Gym.build/Script-23112B16D73A4B02959D4FE9.sh

mkdir -p /Users/sword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mage-ios-dsifsnvwvxethjewoknlrdvajlxe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RENPHO/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/AI Gym.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AWSCore.framework" "/Users/sword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mage-ios-dsifsnvwvxethjewoknlrdvajlxe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RENPHO/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/AI Gym.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/sword/Desktop/aigym/MageFitness/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AWSCore.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/d9889869-120b-11ee-b796-7a03568b17ac/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Answer (score 3):

Open your project by Xcode and Go to **Pods->Target Support Files->Pods-YourProjectName-Frameworks**

Find out code block

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
echo "Symlinked..."
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
fi
```

Replace source="$(readlink "${source}")" by **source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"**

Now you can archive your project in Xcode 15

[image]